Type error: Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<any> | AsyncIterable<any>'
I have a nextjs project that I have implemented a function for add/deleting files on google drive, I initially got this error while developing Type error: Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<any> | AsyncIterable<any>' and solved it by manually assigning ReadableStream<Uint8Array> as one of the expected interface inside the stream library, everything worked fine & properly locally both dev and build but then when I try deploying the same project to vercel, during the build process I get this error
Failed to compile.
./config/serverUtils.ts:70:37
Type error: Argument of type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<any> | AsyncIterable<any>'.
  68 |             const media = {
  69 |                 mimeType: file.type,//'application/octet-stream',
> 70 |                 body: Readable.from(fileBuffer),
     |                                     ^
  71 |                //body: fileBuffer
  72 |             };
  73 |
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

This is the full code producing the error ./config/serverUtils.ts
class GoogleDriveCRUD {
    private oauth2client
    private drive

    constructor() {
        this.oauth2client = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            credentials: {
                type: data.type,
                project_id: data.project_id,
                private_key_id: data.private_key_id,
                private_key: data.private_key,//process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
                client_email: data.client_email,
                client_id: data.client_id,
                // auth_uri: data.auth_uri,
                // token_uri: data.token_uri,
                // auth_provider_x509_cert_url: data.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
                // client_x509_cert_url: data.client_x509_cert_url,
                // universe_domain: data.universe_domain,
            },
            scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
        });
        //this.oauth2client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: refreshToken })
        this.drive = google.drive({
            version: "v3",
            auth: this.oauth2client
        })
    }

    //This function is used to add a file to GDrive
    public async addFile(file: File, folderId: string | void) {
        try {
            const fileBuffer = file.stream();

            const fileMetadata = {
                name: file.name, // The name of the file to be uploaded
                parents: folderId ? [folderId] : undefined, // The ID of the folder where the file should be uploaded
                mimeType: file.type,
            };
        
            const media = {
                mimeType: file.type,//'application/octet-stream',
                body: Readable.from(fileBuffer),
               //body: fileBuffer
            };

            const response = await this.drive.files.create({
                requestBody: fileMetadata,
                media: media,
                fields: "id, imageMediaMetadata",
            })
            
            console.log("Response 1: ", response)
            //console.log("Response 1: ", response.imageMediaMetadata)
            return response.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    //This function helps delete a file from GDrive
    public async deleteFile(driveId: string) {
        try {
            const response = await this.drive.files.delete({
                fileId: driveId
            })
            const res = await this.drive.files.get({
                fileId: ""
            })
            console.log(response)
            //console.log("Response: ", response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}


Since you were in development environment, stream library was stored locally in your project's node_modules ,the problem is probably that you are including node_modules in .gitignore file, so there's no node_modules in your repository, and when you deploy to vercel it installs libraries without changes you made in your project. I think it's better for you to use module augmentation than changing code in node_modules.
